# Best way to toggle between the state of show() and hide() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code which switches between the states of `hide()` and `show()` of *show prices* `button`.I am aware about `.toggle()` in **jQuery**.But I couldn't find a workaround of it in this instance.
When I click the `button` the `<p></p>` element is appended to **.msg** class in the `div` and when I click it once again it hides it state by removing the `<p></p>` element from the DOM (which is in the `else` block).

I have managed to come up with a solution which works well using `If..else`, yet it doesn't feel right or the best way to do it. I find this solution naive and want to know what I can do to further optimize this code.

Following is the code:

```js
(function() {
  //$('.not-interested').hide();
  $('.msg').hide();

  var showPrice = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var vacation = $(this).closest('.vacation');
    var button = vacation.find('button');
    if ((!vacation.hasClass('present'))) {
      var price = +vacation.data('price');
      var vacation_place = vacation.find('h3').text();
      var msg = $("<p style='text-align:center;line-height:24px;font-size:13px;'>Price for " + vacation_place + " is: " + (3 * price) + " </p>");
      vacation.find('.msg').prepend(msg).show();
      vacation.addClass('present');
    } else if ((e.type == 'click' && e.toElement.localName == 'button') || e.type == 'showAll') {

      //console.log(e.toElement.localName);
      //vacation.on('click','button')){
      //console.log(e.toElement);
      //console.log(vacation.on('click','button').context);
      //console.log(button);
      vacation.removeClass('present');
      vacation.find('.msg').hide().find('p').remove();
    }

  };

  var removePrice = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var vacation = $(this).closest('.vacation');
    vacation.find('div.msg').hide();
    //vacation.on('click.price','button',showPrice);
  };

  $('.vacation').on('click.show', 'button', showPrice);
  $('.vacation').on('showAll.price', showPrice); // creating a custom event

  $('.show-all-price').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.vacation').trigger('showAll.price'); // firing a custom event on click of an anchor
  });
})();
```

```css
body,
ul {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "sans-serif";
  color: #fff;
}
.show-all {
  width: 100px;
  background: #597C80;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #2A3F41;
}
.show-all a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2A3F41;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
li h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
li > div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
li button {
  width: 100%;
  background: #377C37;
  color: #333;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 9px;
}
button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  /* padding: 8px 13px 6px;*/
}
li a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #597C80;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="show-all">
    <a href="#" class="show-all-price">Show all</a>
  </div>
  <ul id="vacation-list">
    <li class="vacation" data-price="395">
      <h3>Hawaiian Vacation</h3>
      <div>
        <button>Show all prices</button>
        <div class="msg">
          <a href="#" class="not-interested">Not Interested</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="vacation" data-price="315">
      <h3>American Vacation</h3>
      <div>
        <button>Show all prices</button>
        <div class="msg">
          <a href="#" class="not-interested">Not Interested</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="vacation" data-price="420">
      <h3>French Vacation</h3>
      <div>
        <button>Show all prices</button>
        <div class="msg">
          <a href="#" class="not-interested">Not Interested</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

I've also tried using `.on()` and `.off()` with name spacing but couldn't figured how to do it appropriately.

Here's the code with `.on()` and `.off()` switching:

```
(function(){
//$('.not-interested').hide();
$('.msg').hide();

var showPrice = function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    var vacation = $(this).closest('.vacation');
    var button = vacation.find('button');

    var price = +vacation.data('price');
    var vacation_place = vacation.find('h3').text();
    var msg = $("<p style='text-align:center;line-height:24px;font-size:13px;'>Price for " + vacation_place + " is: " + (3 * price) + " </p>");
    vacation.find('.msg').prepend(msg).show();

    vacation.on('click.remove','button',removePrice);

};

   var removePrice = function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     var vacation = $(this).closest('.vacation');
     vacation.find('div.msg').hide().find('p').remove();
     vacation.on('click.price','button',showPrice);
   };

   $('.vacation').on('click.price','button',showPrice);
   $('.vacation').on('showAll.price',showPrice); // creating a custom event

   $('.show-all-price').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.vacation').trigger('showAll.price'); // firing a custom event on click of an anchor
   });
})();
```

**Note:**,`e.toElement.localName == 'button'` doesn't work in **IE**.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you trying to hide and show, and why doesn't `.toggle` do what you need? What does `.on` and `.off` have to do with it, those are for event handlers and have nothing to do with toggling visibility.

Comment: If you have working code, and you're looking for help in improving the style, a better place to post is codereview.stackexchange.com. SO is for help with making code work.

Comment: Instead of `e.toElement.localName == 'button'`, try `$(this).is("button")`.

Comment: @barmar.Oh sorry, I forgot to mention. I will edit the question..btw, you can run the snippet and check for yourself that when I click _show prices_ `button` If shows and hide..

Comment: Yes, it does. You should change the button to `Hide all prices` when the user clicks on it.

Comment: I have a working solution. I am asking how can I refactor this code to make it work better.

Comment: Like I said, that's what Code Review is for.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wasn't aware about it!

Comment: What do you mean by wanting a workaround. A workaround is a way to do get around the fact that something doesn't work.

Comment: I couldn't find how to implement .`toggle()` in this case

Comment: I wouldn't keep prepending and removing the description each time. I would keep them in the HTML, and have spans for the place and price. Then you can use `vacation.show().find(".place").text(vacation_place).end().find(".price").text(3 * price);`

Comment: `vacation.toggle().find(".place").text(vacation_place).end().find(".price").text(3 * price);`

Comment: `vacation.find('.msg').prepend(msg).toggle();` should work.

Comment: Does it really work? Click "Show all prices" under "French Vacation". Then click the "Show all" button at the top. is that what should happen?

Comment: You only use `.toggle` when you want to hide it if it's showing, and show it if it's hiding. You don't use it if you know which direction you want to go. Then you use `.hide()` or `.show()`.

Comment: The Show All button shouldn't toggle them, it should just show them all.

Comment: `vacation.find('.msg').prepend(msg).toggle();` works but it keeps on prepending..

Comment: So is the problem you're trying to fix that the Show All button doesn't show them all, but toggles each of them?

Comment: @JohnS Yes it works , "show all" will display all the vacations and hide them when clicked again

Comment: I had the problem of `p` getting prepended so I used `show()` and `hide()`. Show all works fine with this code as its just calling showPrices in its events handler.

Comment: @Barmar I want to toggle between `p` the text that I am prepending. **vacation** is the `li` item I don't want to toggle list item.

Comment: If some are showing, and some are hidden, how do you know whether Show All should show them all or hide them all?

Comment: `.toggle()` can be used for the button in each vacation. It can't be used for the Show All button, because that needs to decide whether to show or hide depending on some global state, not whether that specific element is already showing.

Comment: Yes, that is also an issue.Thanks for letting me know."Show all" doesn't really show all when some are shown.It hides the rest and shows the hidden ones.

Comment: The problem with your design is that the Show All button simply simulates clicking on each vacation's Show Prices button. But since those buttons toggle, it doesn't work right. You need a different function for show all and hide all.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking to separate both of them

Comment: There's no need to use a custom event. You might also want to check if all prices are shown by comparing how many vacation elements have the "present" class to how many there are in all, like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03j4jzvz/)

Comment: That's very neat @JohnS. A good solution perhaps.Also it fixes few bugs of "showing all" when few **vacations** are displayed..!!Thanks.